# How to use any with subquery returning bigint[] value?

Tags: java, jooq

I want to fetch all rows from the `original_content` where `id` is in the `pipeline_status.oc_version` column where `pipeline_status.uuid`=`4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc`- I have 2 PostgreSQL queries that give me the expected result and I'd like to translate either of them to jOOQ:

```sql
SELECT oc.* FROM original_content oc
WHERE oc.id = ANY(SELECT unnest(pipeline_status.oc_version) FROM pipeline_status WHERE pipeline_status.uuid='4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc' AND pipeline_status.oc_version IS NOT NULL)
-- or 
SELECT oc.* FROM  original_content oc
WHERE oc.id = ANY(array(SELECT ps.oc_version FROM pipeline_status ps WHERE ps.uuid='4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc' AND pipeline_status.oc_version IS NOT NULL))
```

I have the DSL generated, and I did something like

```java
dslContext.select(
            ORIGINAL_CONTENT.asterisk()
        )
        .from(ORIGINAL_CONTENT)
        .where(ORIGINAL_CONTENT.ID.eq(
                DSL.any(DSL.select(PIPELINE_STATUS.OC_VERSION).from(PIPELINE_STATUS).where(PIPELINE_STATUS.UUID.eq(pipelineUuid)))
            )
        )
```

However, I get an error:

> Cannot resolve method 'eq(QuantifiedSelect<Record1<T>>)'

How do I fix that?

My SQL:

```sql
create table public.pipeline_status
(
    uuid                     varchar(50) not null primary key,
    oc_version bigint[]
);


create table original_content
(
    id            bigserial primary key,
    name          varchar(50)                                        not null,
    created_at    timestamp default (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'::text) not null
);

insert into pipeline_status (uuid, oc_version)
values  ('4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc', '{1020,1021}');

insert into original_content (id, name,  created_at)
OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE
values (1001, 'Name2', '2024-03-22 06:33:12.574244'),
       (1021, 'Name2', '2024-03-22 07:33:32.574244'),
       (1020, 'Name1',  '2024-03-22 09:33:31.574244'),
       (1040, 'Name1',  '2024-03-22 07:33:51.574244'),
       (1002, 'Name3',  '2024-03-22 07:33:13.574244');

SELECT oc.* FROM original_content oc
WHERE oc.id = ANY(SELECT unnest(pipeline_status.oc_version) FROM pipeline_status WHERE pipeline_status.uuid='4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc' AND pipeline_status.oc_version IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Is `OC_VERSION` an array column?

Comment: yes I added my sql with the tables' definitions, I use jooq `3.18.7`and I generate the dsl

Comment: In your updated question, you're not using `ANY(ARRAY(SELECT ..))` anymore. Can you please consolidate your question? I'm not sure anymore what you're actually looking for.

Comment: I want to fetch all the original_content where id is in the `pipeline_status.oc_version` column for `pipeline_status.uuid`='4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc' - I don't care how the query would look like I just want it to work - I noticed that unnest also work so I thought I'd add it if it's easier to use in jooq - if you manage to translate any of these queries to jooq I'd appreciate

Comment: I dont get why you put string to bigint[] value.  ('{1020,1021}')

Comment: I guess you have some design problem

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez: That is just PostgreSQL's array notation. I don't see any design problem in the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Existing attempts

Using `UNNEST()` in the `SELECT` clause is a very weird, historic PostgreSQL specific feature that isn't supported by jOOQ out of the box, although, you can obviously use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) to get it to work, e.g.

```java
DSL.field("unnest({0})", 
  ORIGINAL_CONTENT.ID.getDataType(), 
  PIPELINE_STATUS.OC_VERSION
);
```

The `oc.id = ANY(array(SELECT ps.oc_version ..))` approach seems wrong to me, but I assume it works because PostgreSQL doesn't properly support multi dimensional arrays. The `ARRAY(SELECT array_column)` expression should produce a `BIGINT[][]` type, but that doesn't exist in PostgreSQL, which just flattens it. This isn't supported in jOOQ, which assumes multi dimensional arrays are supported properly, so you'll get a wrong `Field<Long[][]>` type, when you wanted a `Field<Long[]>` type.

In other words, both of these PostgreSQL specific quirks aren't supported out of the box by jOOQ.

#### Alternative approach

But I'd rewrite your SQL version of the query to this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM original_content oc
EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM pipeline_status pc
  WHERE pc.uuid = '4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc'
  AND pc.oc_version IS NOT NULL
  AND oc.id = ANY(pc.oc_version)
)
```

With jOOQ:

```java
ctx.selectFrom(ORIGINAL_CONTENT)
   .where(exists(
        selectOne()
        .from(PIPELINE_STATUS)
        .where(PIPELINE_STATUS.UUID.eq("4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc"))
        .and(PIPELINE_STATUS.OC_VERSION.isNotNull())
        .and(ORIGINAL_CONTENT.ID.eq(any(PIPELINE_STATUS.OC_VERSION)))
   ))
   .fetch();
```

Comment: I used the query you suggested, thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your initial SQL query (and not rewrite it/simplify it as in [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78218471/6309)):

```sql
SELECT oc.* FROM original_content oc
WHERE oc.id = ANY(SELECT unnest(pipeline_status.oc_version) FROM pipeline_status
WHERE pipeline_status.uuid='4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc' AND
      pipeline_status.oc_version IS NOT NULL)
```

Looking at "[jOOQ / 4.12.9. Quantified comparison predicate](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.20/manual-single-page/#quantified-comparison-predicate)", using quantified comparison predicates (`ANY`, `ALL`) should help: since your case involves comparing a single column (`oc.id`) against a set of values produced by a subquery, you can use the [`DSL.any()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#any-T...-) method in combination with a subselect.

However, because you are dealing with an array column (`oc_version`), and you want to compare each `id` against any element within these arrays, you should first unnest ([`unnest(Field<?> cursor)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#unnest(org.jooq.Field))) the array with a subquery, and then use `DSL.any()` for the comparison.

The relevant [`unnest` method](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#unnest(org.jooq.Field)) method would then be:

```java
DSL.unnest(Field<T[]> field)
```

It takes a `Field<T[]>`, where `T[]` is an array type, and it expands the array into a set of rows. In your case, `T` would be `Long` or a similar numeric type matching your `oc_version` array elements.

```java
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.field;
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.table;

// Assuming these are your generated table and field references
var ORIGINAL_CONTENT = table("original_content");
var PIPELINE_STATUS = table("pipeline_status");
var ID = field("id", Long.class);
var OC_VERSION = field("oc_version", Long[].class);
var UUID = field("uuid", String.class);

String pipelineUuid = "4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc";

var correctedQuery = dslContext
        .select(ORIGINAL_CONTENT.asterisk())
        .from(ORIGINAL_CONTENT)
        .where(
            ORIGINAL_CONTENT.field(ID).eq(
                DSL.any(
                    DSL.select(DSL.unnest(PIPELINE_STATUS.field(OC_VERSION).cast(Long[].class)))
                    .from(PIPELINE_STATUS)
                    .where(PIPELINE_STATUS.field(UUID).eq(pipelineUuid))
                    .and(PIPELINE_STATUS.field(OC_VERSION).isNotNull())
                )
            )
        )
        .fetch();

// Execute and print the query
System.out.println(correctedQuery);
```

`DSL.unnest(PIPELINE_STATUS.field(OC_VERSION).cast(Long[].class))` is used to convert the `oc_version` array column into a set of rows so that each `id` from the `original_content` table can be compared against each element within those arrays.

---

> I don't use the fields you created like `var OC_VERSION = field("oc_version", Long[].class);`, but instead I use the fields of the generated DSL, so for example: `.and(PIPELINE_STATUS.field(PIPELINE_STATUS.OC_VERSION).isNotNull())`.
> I still get: `Cannot resolve method 'eq(QuantifiedSelect<R>)'`.

That error message should mean a type mismatch between what the `eq()` method expects and what `QuantifiedSelect<R>` provides: the return type of the subquery might not directly match the expected type for a straightforward equality comparison, hence the error.

The correct appraoach should not wrap a generated field with `PIPELINE_STATUS.field()` again. Instead, use the generated fields directly as they are already typed correctly. For instance, if `PIPELINE_STATUS.OC_VERSION` is a generated field representing the `oc_version` column, it should be used directly without additional wrapping.
And when dealing with arrays and the `ANY` function, the comparison might require explicit handling to make sure type compatibility.
That means adjusting the query to properly use the `ANY` function with the expected types. Pseudo-code:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

// Example using generated DSL fields directly
var pipelineUuid = "4f3164b9-6fde-45d6-bd58-86308473b0dc";

var query = dslContext
        .selectFrom(ORIGINAL_CONTENT)
        .where(
            ORIGINAL_CONTENT.ID.eq(
                // Use DSL.any() with a subquery that properly matches the expected type
                DSL.any(
                    DSL.select(PIPELINE_STATUS.OC_VERSION)
                       .from(PIPELINE_STATUS)
                       .where(PIPELINE_STATUS.UUID.eq(pipelineUuid))
                       .and(PIPELINE_STATUS.OC_VERSION.isNotNull())
                       // That might need adjustment depending on the actual type of OC_VERSION
                )
            )
        )
        .fetch();
```

That would end up like [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder)'s [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78218471/6309).

Comment: your solution looks nice but when I don't use the fields you created like `var OC_VERSION = field("oc_version", Long[].class);` but instead I use the fields of the generated dsl so for example `                            .and(PIPELINE_STATUS.field(PIPELINE_STATUS.OC_VERSION).isNotNull())` I still get `Cannot resolve method 'eq(QuantifiedSelect<R>)'`